# Laravel 5 Relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Database Structure:

-Users Table
 -user_id
 -name
 -...

-Follow Table
 -user_id
 -follow_id

so when user follow another it will be inserted in follow table

and when get user followers

```
 $user  = User::where('user_id',$id)->first();


    $user['followers'] = $user->Followers;
    $user['following'] = $user->Following;

return $user;
```

By This Relation in User Model Side

```
public function Followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follow','follow_id','user_id');

}
```

And By This Relation in Follow Model Side

```
public function getUserData()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_id');
   }
```

It Works Fine for me and it gaves me every id But the problem is

that i want to get information about every user returned from this relation

so i should call User Model for each user returned to get his information
 or what ??

Comment: I'm assuming that the `follow_id` is an id from the `users` table

Comment: Yes it is so i want to fetch user information by this id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have you many-to-many relationship set up is almost right.

Firstly, change the `Followers()` method to be `followers()` as Laravel follows the PSR-2 standard.

Secondly, this isn't essential but change the `user_id` column in the `users` table to be just `id`. This is a laravel convension that does not need to be followed, however, at this point I don't see any reason not to follow it. I am assuming that you have something like:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

in your `User` model. If you change your `user_id` column to `id` you won't have to have the above declaration anymore. 
(If you don't have that line in and you want to continue using `user_id` as the primary key you WILL have to add that line to your `User` model.

Thirdly, change the relationship type in `followers()` to be:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower', 'user_id', 'follow_id'); 
    //follower is the table name, user_id is column that relates to the current model and follow_id is the column that is for the relationships
}
```

With all of the above done you can now get a user with all of their followers by doing:

```
$user = User::with('followers')->find($id);
```

This will allow you to get the followers by simply doing:

```
$user->followers
```

At this point you can not get rid of you `Follow` model as you generally wont need a model for a `pivot` table.

To get the following relationship just add:

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower', 'follow_id', 'user'); 
}
```

to your `User` model.

Again to access this you can either:

```
$user = User::with('following')->find($id);

or if you have already have the user model and the relationship isn't loaded you can:

$user->load('following'); //in this case following is the name of the method where you have declared the relationship.
```

For more information please refer to the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many and http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Hope this helps!